# Trying to get for searching lattitude and longitude of places using vba from a web page. find button clicking through vba is not working

Tags: excel, vba

When executing this code it is filling the required text box on the website but pressing the find button gives the output 'not found' in the message box.

Subsequently, if i manually just click in the text box on the filled value and then click the find button, it shows the desired result.

How can I make this work?

```
Public Sub experiment()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.navigate "https://www.latlong.net/"

     Do
     DoEvents
     Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

     Dim doc As HTMLDocument
     Set doc = ie.document
     Dim inputElement As HTMLInputElement

     Set inputElement = doc.getElementsByClassName("width70")(0)     
     inputElement.Value = "Delhi Airport, India"

     ie.Visible = True

     doc.getElementById("btnfind").Click


     Do

     DoEvents

     Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than IE automation and interacting with the page as a user would, the code below should emulate the request triggered by the `'Find'` button on the page, but you need to assign a value to `placeName` in the code (currently it is `"Delhi Airport, India"`).

If you are interested in only the co-ordinates (and no other information on the rest of the page), then this approach might be okay for you.

You'll need to add a reference (`Tools > References > Scroll down and tick Microsoft XML, v6.0 > OK`) before trying to run the code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Experiment()
    Dim placeName As String
    placeName = "Delhi Airport, India"

    Dim WebClient As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Set WebClient = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    With WebClient
        .Open "POST", "https://www.latlong.net/_spm4.php", True
        .setRequestHeader ":authority", "www.latlong.net"
        .setRequestHeader ":method", "POST"
        .setRequestHeader ":path", "/_spm4.php"
        .setRequestHeader ":scheme", "https"
        .setRequestHeader "accept", "*/*"
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "origin", "https://www.latlong.net"
        .setRequestHeader "referer", "https://www.latlong.net/"
        .setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest"

        Dim bodyToSend As String
        bodyToSend = "c1=" & Application.EncodeURL(placeName) & "&action=gpcm&cp="

        .send bodyToSend
        .waitForResponse

        MsgBox ("Server's response to the request for Place Name '" & placeName & "' is " & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & .responseText)
    End With
End Sub
```

You can access the server's response (which will contain the co-ordinates if the request was successful) with `WebClient.responseText` (or just `.responseText` inside the `With` statement) -- and then do what you need to with it.